# Android: Multiple activity instances launched by same intent. Bring one uniquely to foreground?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm struggling with my app that launches multiple instances of the
same Activity using the same intent. My main activity is of class type
A and it does a startActivity() of two children that are of the same
class type B. So we have B1 and B2 launched. If B1 and B2 are both
paused (by pushing back button and making sure finish() is not invoked
on them so they are truly paused), how can A uniquely bring either B1
or B2 to the foreground again? I do want to launch a new B activity. I
want to uniquely bring B1 or B2 to the foreground.

so both B1 and B2 were created like this...
Intent intent = new Intent(context, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);

Now I want A to bring B1 (or B2) to the foreground/front so I use the
below code, but how do I distinguish B1 or B2 when starting the
activity? This only brings the last instance of B that was on top to
the foreground.

Intent intent = new Intent(context, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);

I've tried keeping around references to B1 and B2 and doing something
like this, but this also only goes to the last instance of activity
class B that was on top...

Intent intent = new Intent(B1context, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
B1context.startActivity(intent);

I even tried this, but it still doesnt get me my unique B1 or B2...
Intent intent = B1.getIntent(); // i.e. the original intent that
started me
startActivity(intent); // still only brings to front the last B that
was on top.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about making a C that extends B, so B can be B1 and C can be B2 ? This really doesn't answer your question, but you could use it if no one can answer this

Comment: Maybe you can achieve it via an `<activity-alias>`. You need B1 and B2 to be separate components, which normally would be separate activity classes.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't.  The purpose of NEW_TASK is to launch separate "applications" as the user sees them.  If you are using this to try to manipulate the flow through your app, you are abusing it (and breaking things like recent tasks etc).

You can work around this by making them actual separate classes through subclasses, but before doing that please stop and think about whether what you are doing here is actually correct at all.  There are only a few places where NEW_TASK should be used -- launchers, switches from notifications, etc.  In all of those cases there is a pretty unique identity of what the user is launching to.  Whatever you are doing should maintain those semantics.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution :

```
Intent mIntent1 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
mIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Intent mIntent2 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
Intent[] list = new Intent[2];
list[0] = mIntent1;
list[1] = mIntent2;
startActivities(list);
```