# Launch 2 intent but not at the same time

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem that if I start an intent using

```
try{
    startIntent1(); //Add Contact Intent
} finally {
    startIntent2(); // Contact Picker Intent
}
```

they start together.... is there a way that after my intent1 then intent2 will launch?

Comment: You can use a thread to start the intent with a little delay.

Comment: Explain your more. What you want to do.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for all your solutions but I've managed to do it by using startActivityOnResult

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

        context.startActivityForResult(intent, 6);
```

then on ActivityResult

```
case 6 :
        ContactPicker cp = new ContactPicker(this);
        cp.doLaunchContactPicker(); //launch the intent for contact picker
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use  the handler not put in finally

```
int duration = 1500; // milliseconds
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startIntent2();
    }
}, duration);
```

Comment: so the problem now in this code is... what if the user is slow in adding contact? so while he's adding contact for like 10sec  intent2 will start?

Answer (score 1):

As you kept `startIntent2()` in `finally{}` this will fire anyhow whether any exception occured or not.

if you want to start `startIntent2()` after `startIntent1()` you can write `startIntent2()` at `onCreate()` method of `startIntent1()` activity else you can also go with `Thread`.

Comment: Is there a method that checks an intent if it is finish?

Comment: @RonPelayo do you want that if first intent's activity should finish then only second intent should start..??

Comment: Exactly! :) but I think startActivityOnResult is my best solution in my problem.. thankyou for the suggestion

Comment: @RonPelayo exactly it is.. else you can start another intent from adding content activity and finish currnet adding content activity else you go with startActivityOnResult.. :)

Comment: can you give me an example about adding content activity? :)

Comment: AddContact is your own activity or AndroidDefault AddContact you are using.?

Answer (score 1):

for Multiple Intent you need the following`

```
Intent mIntent1 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
mIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Intent mIntent2 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
Intent[] list = new Intent[2];
list[0] = mIntent1;
list[1] = mIntent2;
startActivities(list);`
```

Originally shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180512/android-multiple-activity-instances-launched-by-same-intent-bring-one-uniquely)